# Upload iPad ONLY app to iTunes

Tags: xcode, ipad, app-store-connect, itunes

I have tried the following, but iTunes still wants me to upload iPhone screenshots.

1.) `Devicefamily` set to `2` `info.plist`.

[image]

2.) `General` - `Targets` - `Deployment Info` - `Devices` is set to `iPad`

[image]

3.) App Icon checked ONLY for `iPad`.

[image]

4.) All assets being used across project in `Assets.xcassets` are checked for `iPad` ONLY.

[image]

I have attached screenshots for all four points mentioned above. On iTunes it still wants me to upload screen shots for iPhone.

[image]

Please assist, I am having a hard time finding the needle in the haystack.

Comment: Select the Build first and upload the SS for iPad only,  itunes will detect automatically depending on you build (iPA).

Comment: hi @NaumanMalik Thanks for the reply, can you please clarify what do you mean by selecting the build first. Can you attach a screenshot of where i can select the build.

Comment: On the same screen where you have options of Screen Shot Scroll down and select build and than Add screen shot for iPad only.

Comment: @NaumanMalik Big Thanks!! Please post an answer.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same screen where you have options of Screen Shot Scroll down Select the Build first and upload the SS for iPad only, itunes will detect automatically depending on you build (iPA).